# Any spatial index support in the standard PostgreSQL installation?

Tags: postgresql, spatial-index

I'm new to PostgreSQL.

For the default install of PostgreSQL (no extension like PostGIS), 
if there's geographic fields defined in my table, then what kinds of index does PostgreSQL support?

I didn't find any information on the spatial index in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GiST, [just like PostGIS uses](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch04.html#id2794434).

But why don't you install PostGIS in your database?